# Image gets rotated on Note 10 and One Plus devices in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, file-upload, bitmapimage

I need to upload an image to the server. For that I capture image(or take an image from the gallery) that image is placed in its exact position but when I upload image to server the image gets rotated.
I have googled also but no luck.
Below is my code:

```
private fun chooseImage() {
        val items = arrayOf<CharSequence>("Camera", "Gallery", "Cancel")
        val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        builder.setTitle("Add Attachment")
        builder.setItems(items) { dialog, item ->
            try {
                if (items[item] == "Camera") {
                    takePhotoFromCamera()

                } else if (items[item] == "Gallery") {
                    choosePhotoFromGallary()

                } else if (items[item] == "Cancel") {
                    dialog.dismiss()
                }
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
        }
        builder.show()
    }

    fun choosePhotoFromGallary() {
        val galleryIntent = Intent(
            Intent.ACTION_PICK,
            MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
        )
        startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, GALLERY)
    }

    private fun takePhotoFromCamera() {
        val intent = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
        startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA)
    }

    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

        if (requestCode == GALLERY) {
            if (data != null) {
                val contentURI: Uri = data.getData()
                try {
                    var bitmap =
                        MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.contentResolver, contentURI)
                    imagePath = bitmapToFile(bitmap,this).toString()

                   var bitmapNew =  handleSamplingAndRotationBitmap(this,contentURI)

                    binding.circleImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmapNew)
                    AppInstance.profileimagePath = imagePath

                } catch (e: IOException) {
                    e.printStackTrace()
                    showToast(this, "Failed!")
                }
            }
        } else if (requestCode == CAMERA) {
            val thumbnail = data!!.getExtras().get("data") as Bitmap

            imagePath= bitmapToFile(thumbnail,this).toString()

            Glide.with(this)
                .load(imagePath).into(binding.circleImageView);

            AppInstance.profileimagePath = imagePath


        }
    }
```

And this is :

```
 @Throws(IOException::class)
    public fun handleSamplingAndRotationBitmap(context: Context, selectedImage: Uri?): Bitmap? {
        val MAX_HEIGHT = 800
        val MAX_WIDTH = 800

        // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
        val options = BitmapFactory.Options()
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true
        var imageStream: InputStream = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(selectedImage)
        BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream, null, options)
        imageStream.close()

        // Calculate inSampleSize
        options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, MAX_WIDTH, MAX_HEIGHT)

        // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false
        imageStream = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(selectedImage)
        var img = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream, null, options)
        img = selectedImage?.let { rotateImageIfRequired(context, img, it) }
        return img
    }
```

bitmap to file :

```
fun bitmapToFile(bitmap: Bitmap, context: Context): Uri {
    // Get the context wrapper
    val dateFormat = SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HH_mm_ss")
    val currentTimeStamp = dateFormat.format(Date())
    val wrapper = ContextWrapper(context)

    // Initialize a new file instance to save bitmap object
    var file = wrapper.getDir("Images",Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
    file = File(file,"$currentTimeStamp.jpg")

    var bitmapNew = bitmap

    try{
        val imageRotation: Int = getImageRotation(file)
        if (imageRotation != 0)
            bitmapNew = getBitmapRotatedByDegree(bitmap, imageRotation)!!

        // Compress the bitmap and save in jpg format
        val stream: OutputStream = FileOutputStream(file)
        bitmapNew.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,70,stream)
        stream.flush()
        stream.close()
    }catch (e: IOException){
        e.printStackTrace()
    }

    // Return the saved bitmap uri
    return Uri.parse(file.absolutePath)
}
```

Your kind support will be highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `val imageRotation: Int = getImageRotation(file)` You should not get the rotation from a File object but from your original data.getData() uri. Dont use the File class at all under 10.

Comment: Is it resolved now?

Comment: @AnshulTyagi yes actually issue was on bitmaptoFile function. I changed that and it works :)

Answer (score 1):

I believe you should use the proper Exif interface to determine the correct image orientation.

Orientation of an image, is tied to the sensor that captured it. Sensor orientation is how the hardware is assembled and put in the case (phone/device). Some manufacturers/devices have their cameras physically rotated (for "reasons"), and are programmed to write the Exif information indicating the correct rotation.

What does this mean?

In practice, it means that after you take/receive an image, you must make sure you read this Exif rotation before acting on it.

What follows is a very simple (pseudo-code) of what you need.

(note: latest version at this time, July 2020, is `1.2.0`)

1. Import the Google EXIF dependency: `implementation "androidx.exifinterface:exifinterface:$exifinterfaceVersion"`
2. Assume you have a file pointing to an Image... you'd have a function like this:

```
 private fun getImageRotation(imageFile: File): Int {
        val ei = ExifInterface(imageFile.path)
        return ei.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION,
                ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_UNDEFINED)
    }
```

3. After obtaining the rotation from the Exif interface, you can act on it, let's imagine you want to rotate images that are NOT "normal"; you could do something like this:

```
fun ensureRotationIsNormal(imageBitmap: Bitmap, imageFile: File): Bitmap {
        try {
            val angle = when (getImageRotation(imageFile)) {
                ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90 -> 90
                ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180 -> 180
                ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270 -> 270
                // these are already correctly oriented, return the image.
                ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL -> return imageBitmap
                else -> return imageBitmap
            }

            return rotateBitmapWithAngle(imageBitmap, angle.toFloat())

        } catch (e: IOException) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Couldn't rotate image. Exception: " + e.message)
            return imageBitmap
        }
    }
```

And the `rotate` fun is simple:

```
    fun rotateBitmapWithAngle(imageBitmap: Bitmap, angle: Float): Bitmap {
        val matrix = Matrix()
        matrix.postRotate(angle)
        return Bitmap.createBitmap(
           imageBitmap, 
           0, 
           0, 
           imageBitmap.width, 
           imageBitmap.height, 
           matrix, 
           true)
    }
```

For what is worth, these are all the parameters for `createBitmap`:

```
     * @param source   The bitmap we are subsetting
     * @param x        The x coordinate of the first pixel in source
     * @param y        The y coordinate of the first pixel in source
     * @param width    The number of pixels in each row
     * @param height   The number of rows
     * @param m        Optional matrix to be applied to the pixels
     * @param filter   true if the source should be filtered.
     *                   Only applies if the matrix contains more than just
     *                   translation.
```

I have use this *similar* method before. Not sure if there's a better way but this works. You will need to decide what "logic" you want in your "ensureRotationIsNormal", and also any other business rule you want, but these are the "core" parts.